# Why does cross_val_score always report the same score for each fold?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm running a Scikit-learn pipeline using cross validation via `cross_val_score`.

But after running it a couple of times the results for each fold are always the same. I'm bothered by this because shouldn't the splits be random?

This is the relevant part of my code:

```python
pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('vect', CountVectorizer(preprocessor=clean_text_custom, max_features=MAX_NB_WORDS, strip_accents='unicode')),
    ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
    ('clf', OneVsRestClassifier(LinearSVC(),n_jobs=-1)),
])

cross_val_score(pipeline, data, binary_label_data, cv=5,scoring='f1_micro')
# array([ 0.25129587,  0.37780563,  0.33195376,  0.31269861,  0.14555337])

# then i run it again and I get he exact same scores for each fold
cross_val_score(pipeline, data, binary_label_data, cv=5,scoring='f1_micro')
# array([ 0.25129587,  0.37780563,  0.33195376,  0.31269861,  0.14555337])
```

Comment: Depends on your target data. Whats the shape of `binary_label_data`. Is this multi-class or multi-label. If multi-label, then a simple Kfold will be used, which will not shuffle the data.

Comment: @VivekKumar yes it is multi label. Is it advisable for me to shuffle the data myself prior to feeding it to cross validation?

Comment: You can use a cv iterator which handles this and pass that as value for `cv` in `cross_val_score`. Please [look here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#cross-validation-iterators)